# How to access native APIs from Mono (command-line) app?

Tags: c#, mono

Is it possible (and if so, how) to call an external API from an ordinary command-line Mono app?

For example: I've installed Mono on my Mac via [this page](http://www.mono-project.com/download/) and have been happily writing command-line apps, but now want to access some simple CoreFoundation API.  I really don't want to switch to Xamarin.Mac just for that.  Is this possible?

As a closely related question, can I create my own shared library exposing a C API, and somehow invoke this from my Mono app?

Comment: Are these the droids you are looking for? http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/

Comment: Those were _exactly_ the droids I was looking for.  If you care about such things, feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mono Docs cover P/Invoke here : http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/

Citing:

> The Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) is designed to make it “easy” to interoperate with existing code. In principle, all you need to do is create a DllImport function declaration for the existing code to invoke, and the runtime will handle the rest. For example:
>
> `[DllImport ("libc.so")]
>   private static extern int getpid ();`

Because you specifically asked about Mac:

> Note: Mono uses GLib to load libraries, and GLib has a bug on Mac OS X where it doesn’t use a .dylib extension, but instead uses the Unix .so extension. While this should eventually be fixed, the current workaround is to write a .config file which maps to the .dylib file, e.g. [and so on ...]

Comment: Love it how they put "easy" in quotation marks haha.